# Convert audio file using another audio file as template in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have some `.mp3` audio files, with different "configuration" like sample rate, bit rate, etc.

For my app, one of them is working and the rest, not.

How can I convert the rest of them using the working file's "configuration"?

Metadata of [two sample files](http://we.tl/psWYLm7knv):

```
~/Downloads ❯ ffmpeg -i working.mp3 -i not_working.mp3
ffmpeg version 2.8.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mp3 @ 0x7fd2d380da00] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 33.
[mp3 @ 0x7fd2d380da00] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from 'working.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf52.64.2
  Duration: 00:00:00.65, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, mono, s16p, 64 kb/s
[mp3 @ 0x7fd2d4008800] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 417.
Input #1, mp3, from 'not_working.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:01.83, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 46 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 46 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : LAME3.99r
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! (_ironic_)

Comment: Why does your app not play certain MP3 files? Why not fix the app instead of having to re-encode?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, because it's a legacy code and I don't understand how it works and like all legacy code "it worked well until now". And leaving this aside, I am also curios if it's possible. Didn't find a way, though I find this feature very logically.

Comment: Consider making another question by posting your code for suggestions why it does not work with certain MP3 files, and provide links to files that do work and files that do not work. However, if you don't get any results you can fallback to this less-than-optimal solution of re-encoding. Anyway, you need to show the complete output of: `ffmpeg -i works.mp3 -i notwork.mp3`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, I have updated my question.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that the most obvious parameters are identical, other than start and encoder metadata. Can you provide links to each file?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, I have selected the wrong files. I uploaded now the correct working and not working files and updated the metadata

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change the channel layout and/or sample rate:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a libmp3lame -ar 22050 -ac 1 output.mp3
```

Try 3 commands: one without `-ar 22050`, one without `-ac 1`, and one with both as shown above.